# Friendly buzzing sound?

Tags: games

I'm making a puzzle game based on honey bees. I introduced sound effects, but testers are uncomfortable with the occasional buzzing sounds produced. I just have an occasional buzz-buzz after certain moves. I'd like to somehow make it friendlier. It seems that people have a natural aversion to anything that buzzes. I need to maintain bee based sound effects but to somehow avoid excessive buzzing. Any ideas? Musical buzzing? I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: are there any visual clues showing bees when the buzz happens ?

Comment: Try something "honey" related.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered getting voice actors to say "buzz, buzz!" instead of actual buzzing noises? That would be very cutesy & friendly.

Comment: Not a bad idea! Maybe not have them actually say "buzz" though, but by having a voice actor, or yourself, make buzzing noises then you should easily be able to make some playful / friendly sounds.